# How can connect MySql Online Database to C# desktop application

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I am creating desktop application in c# but i wont to use Online Database created in mysql.

```
String mysqlConnectionString = "Server=216.14.120.105;Database=xxx_keys;UID=xxx_root;Password=xxx;Port=3306";
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(mysqlConnectionString);
connection.Open();
```

this is the code i am using but i got an error unable to access host.

where i am wrong and if you have any proper code or details then give me.

Comment: Man, you're exposing your database root password!

Comment: It could be a networking issue (firewall), or simply that MySQL server (by default) won't allow connections from remote hosts.

Comment: @haim770: This isn't SQL Server.  :)  Every install of MySQL i've ever seen came out of the box with TCP/IP enabled.

Comment: your connection string is formatted just. I think a problem of remote access to your database. Maybe resreint access level permissions or incorrect address.

Comment: What is the *exact* error message you're getting?

Comment: @cHao, i'm talking about the root@localhost / root@% issue. see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connecting.html

Comment: Can other tools connect to the database from your own computer?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a MySQL database in local server user "localhost" for server IP as georgi-it also told. But if this is an external database first try to open a telnet connection on dos-prompt to see if there is some firewall block or something like that:

```
telnet 216.14.120.105 3306
```

if you don't get an error message and see a blank page then it means you can reach mysql server

Comment: You might need to install telnet : `pkgmgr /iu:"TelnetClient"` http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771275(v=ws.10).aspx for windows 7 and above